# Add months of zero demand to zoo time series

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, intermittent

I have some intermittent demand data that only includes lines where demand is present. I bring it in via read.csv, and my 2 columns are Date (as date) and Quantity (as integer). Then I convert it to a zoo series and combine the daily demand into monthly demand. My final output is a zoo series with the date being the first day of the month and the summed demand for that month.

My problem is that this zoo series is missing the in between months that have zero demand and I need these to forecast intermittent demand correctly.

For example: I have quantity 2 in date 2013-01-01 and then the next line is quantity 3 in 2013-10-01. I need to add quantity zero to 2013-02-01 through 2013-09-01.

```
Date <- c('1/1/2013','10/1/2013','11/1/2013')
Quantity <- c('2','3','6')

Date <- as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

df <- data.frame(Date, Quantity)
df <- read.zoo(df)
df
```

The zoo series output:

```
2013-01-01  2013-10-01  2013-11-01
         2           3           6
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which means a data sample, the code you tried, the expected output, and any error messages.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

Because "df" is a `zoo` object, you may use `merge.zoo` and its `fill` argument. The current data set is merged with an empty `zoo` object which contains all the desired dates.

```
tt <- seq(min(Date), max(Date), "month")
merge(df, zoo(, tt), fill = 0)

# 2013-01-01 2013-02-01 2013-03-01 2013-04-01 2013-05-01 2013-06-01 2013-07-01 2013-08-01 2013-09-01 2013-10-01 2013-11-01 
#          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          3          6
```

For further examples, see `?merge.zoo` ("extend an irregular series to a regular one").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` to add the missing rows and then set their values to zero.

First, let's create some fake data:

```
# Vector of dates from Jan 1, 2015, to Mar 31, 2015
dates = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-03-31"), by="1 day")

# Let's create data for few of these dates, leaving some out
set.seed(55)
dat = data.frame(dates=dates[sample(1:length(dates), 70)],
                 quantity=sample(1:10, 70, replace=TRUE))
dat = dat[order(dat$dates),]
```

Now let's make believe `dat` is what you imported from a csv file. We want to fill in `quantity`=0 for the missing dates. So first we need to add rows for the missing dates. You can do this by creating a date vector containing all dates from the first date to the last date in your csv file and using the `merge` function. In this case, we've already created that date vector above.

Now merge in rows for the missing dates. The new rows will have `NA` for `quantity`. We'll change those `NA`s to zero below.

```
dat = merge(data.frame(dates), dat, by="dates", all.x=TRUE)

# Set missing values to zero
dat$quantity[is.na(dat$quantity)] = 0
```

Now you can aggregate by month, convert to a `zoo` series, etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly eipi10, thank you! I had something similar, but the merge wasn't working. I changed the naming configuration around so the by="dates" in the merge function matched for both data frames, and now I  was able to get everything in, convert to zoo series, aggregate into monthly demand, and perform Croston's method on monthly demand.

Comment: I'm glad it worked Matt, although I think @Henrik's answer is better if you're using `zoo` objects.