# Inserting rows into a table

Tags: r

I have this table (visit_ts) -

```
Year  Month  Number_of_visits
2011    4        1
2011    6        3
2011    7        23
2011    12       32
2012    1        123
2012    11       3200
```

1. The aim is to insert rows with `Number_of_visits` as 0, for months which are **missing** in the table.
2. Do not insert rows for 2011 where month is 1,2,3 or 2012 where month is 12.

The following code works correctly -

```
vec_month=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
vec_year=c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)
i=1
startyear=head(visit_ts$Year,n=1)
endyear=tail(visit_ts$Year,n=1)
x=head(visit_ts$Month,n=1)
y=tail(visit_ts$Month,n=1)
for (year in vec_year)
{
  if(year %in% visit_ts$Year)
  {
    a=subset(visit_ts,visit_ts$Year==year)
    index= which(!vec_month %in% a$Month)
    for (j in index)
    {
      if((year==startyear & j>x )|(year==endyear & j<y))
      visit_ts=rbind(visit_ts,c(year,j,0))
      else
      {
        if(year!=startyear & year!=endyear)
        visit_ts=rbind(visit_ts,c(year,j,0))
      }
    }}
  else
  {
    i=i+1
  }}
```

As I am new to R I am looking for an alternative/better solution to the problem which would not involve hard-coding the year and month vectors. Also please feel free to point out best programming practices.

Comment: `tidyr::complete` is nice, though you'll still need to chop out the unwanted rows afterwards: `library(tidyr) ; visit_ts %>% complete(Year = 2011:2012, Month = 1:12, fill = list(Number_of_visits = 0))`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks I will look into it. I'm sure chopping off the unwanted rows will be easy.

Comment: You may check `?zoo::merge.zoo` ("extend an irregular series to a regular one [...] with zero fill"). See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104998/add-months-of-zero-demand-to-zoo-time-series/32106474#32106474)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` with `merge` or `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(Year = min(df1$Year):max(df1$Year), Month = 1:12) %>% 
  filter(!(Year == min(df1$Year) & Month %in% 1:3| 
           Year == max(df1$Year) & Month == 12)) %>% 
  left_join(., df1) %>%
  mutate(Number_of_visits=replace(Number_of_visits, is.na(Number_of_visits), 0))
#   Year Month Number_of_visits
#1  2012     1              123
#2  2012     2                0
#3  2012     3                0
#4  2011     4                1
#5  2012     4                0
#6  2011     5                0
#7  2012     5                0
#8  2011     6                3
#9  2012     6                0
#10 2011     7               23
#11 2012     7                0
#12 2011     8                0
#13 2012     8                0
#14 2011     9                0
#15 2012     9                0
#16 2011    10                0
#17 2012    10                0
#18 2011    11                0
#19 2012    11             3200
#20 2011    12               32
```

---

We can make it more dynamic by grouping by 'Year', get the sequence of 'Month' from minimum to maximum in a `list`, `unnest` the column, join with the original dataset (`left_join`) and `replace` the NA values with 0.

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Year) %>% 
     summarise(Month = list(min(Month):max(Month))) %>% 
     unnest(Month) %>%
     left_join(., df1) %>% 
     mutate(Number_of_visits=replace(Number_of_visits, is.na(Number_of_visits), 0))
#     Year Month Number_of_visits
#    <int> <int>            <dbl>
#1   2011     4                1
#2   2011     5                0
#3   2011     6                3
#4   2011     7               23
#5   2011     8                0
#6   2011     9                0
#7   2011    10                0
#8   2011    11                0
#9   2011    12               32
#10  2012     1              123
#11  2012     2                0
#12  2012     3                0
#13  2012     4                0
#14  2012     5                0
#15  2012     6                0
#16  2012     7                0
#17  2012     8                0
#18  2012     9                0
#19  2012    10                0
#20  2012    11             3200
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Year', we get the sequence of `min` to `max` 'Month', join with the original dataset `on` 'Year' and 'Month', replace the NA values to 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[df1[, .(Month=min(Month):max(Month)), Year], 
  on = c("Year", "Month")][is.na(Number_of_visits), Number_of_visits := 0][]
#    Year Month Number_of_visits
# 1: 2011     4                1
# 2: 2011     5                0
# 3: 2011     6                3
# 4: 2011     7               23
# 5: 2011     8                0
# 6: 2011     9                0
# 7: 2011    10                0
# 8: 2011    11                0
# 9: 2011    12               32
#10: 2012     1              123
#11: 2012     2                0
#12: 2012     3                0
#13: 2012     4                0
#14: 2012     5                0
#15: 2012     6                0
#16: 2012     7                0
#17: 2012     8                0
#18: 2012     9                0
#19: 2012    10                0
#20: 2012    11             3200
```

Comment: You're hard coding this part `filter(!(Year == 2011 & Month %in% 1:3| Year == 2012 & Month == 12)) %>%`. I do not necessarily know which months I start with and which months I end with.

Comment: @MayurH That is easy to fix.  Updated the post